# Vue Plugin or Component for Parallax

Tags: javascript, vue.js, plugins, vue-component, parallax

### Background

Consider the following component;

```
<template>

    <div>
        <slot></slot>
    </div>

</template>

<script>

    export default {

        created () {

            // Register the scroll event
            window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);

        },

        methods: {

            /**
             * Handle the window scroll event.
             *
             * @return void
             */
            handleScroll () {
                // Do something...
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Using the above example, very simply, if I use this component multiple times on a page, it will register multiple event listeners for the scroll event (one for each use of the component) which is arguably inefficient.

This got me thinking that maybe a Vue plugin is more suitable as I believe that I can register one event listener which can loop through each occurrence of the  directive/component and apply any necessary changes.

However, I have a few reservations about using a plugin, and as such, wanted to post these here so someone could hopefully shed a little more light for me and assist me in my decision with whether I should use a component or a plugin.

These are my reservations about using a plugin:

- I am not familiar with them i.e. would have to learn how they work
- Are they actually more efficient i.e. will it overcome the problem of registering multiple event listeners
- Are the benefits of a plugin actually worth it (in general)...

The way I intend to use my plugin would be like so i.e. custom directive:

```
<div v-parallax="0.2"></div>
```

*It probably isn't relevant but by applying this directive, the element will then be added to an `items` array, and each item will have their `background-position` updated as the user scrolls/resizes, if the element is in the viewport.*

### My Question

Based on all of the above information, would you recommend a Vue plugin or a Vue component for this particular feature?

**Note** - I am aware that parallax plugins already exist for Vue, but a) they do not work in the way in which I need, and b) I only wish to code for my use specific case i.e. no redundant code.